# How to export all changed/added files from Git?

Tags: git, version-control, msysgit, tortoisegit

I am very new to Git and I have a slight problem.

In SVN *[this feels like an Only Fools and Horses story by uncle Albert.."during the war..."]* when I wanted to update a production site with my latest changes, I'd do a diff in TSVN and export all the changed/added files between two revisions. As you can imagine, it was easy to get those files to a production site afterwards.

However, it seems like I'm unable to find an "export changed files" option in Git. I can do a diff and *see* the changes, I can get a *list* of files, but I can't actually export them. Is there a reasonable way to do this? Am I missing something simple?

Just to clarify once again, I need to export **all** the changes between two specific commits.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

How do you want to export them? You say you already have a list; what more do you want? Supposing you're getting your list with `git diff --name-only ...`

```
git archive --output=<file> HEAD $(git diff --name-only ...)

tar -czf <file> $(git diff --name-only ...)

cp --parents $(git diff --name-only ...) <export-directory>
```

Something like that?

Or you could even use the diff itself - it can be applied with `git apply` (or even `patch`, I believe).

Comment: The first option is working for me! Ideally, I would use the cp variant but keep the folder structure (I'm guessing it's a matter of parameters for git diff?) I can't believe it's that simple..thanks!

Comment: Just saw your edit.. Unfortunately, I can't use `git apply` or `patch`, I only have FTP access to the site :-/

Comment: @dr Hannibal Lecter: Yeah, I figured you needed to pass around actual files. And yeah, command substitution (the `$(...)`) is one of those key things that makes everything possible (and simple) in Linux shells.

Comment: Sadly, I'm currently 50% stuck on Windows, but git bash and cygwin tend to make my life easier.. even though I often have no idea what I'm doing :) Thanks again for the useful info!

Comment: How would you make a diff ignoring files with only modified permissions and not modified contents?

Comment: with every day, I love git more! THIS IS AWESOME!

Comment: to use the third option here, you would probably want to add the `--parents` parameter to CP, so that it preserves file paths in the destination

Comment: how do you perform this in TortoiseGit?

Comment: Adding `--diff-filter=AM` to `git diff` to filter out deleted files and such may be useful

Answer (score 3):

Borrowing from few of the answers in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4541300/export-only-modified-and-added-files-with-folder-structure-in-git), here is another way to export files that are modified in the workspace:

```
git diff --diff-filter=ACMRT --name-only HEAD | xargs tar -rf export.tar
```

You might need to execute the following beforehand to add untracked files, if you need to include them in the diff:

```
git add *
```

[This works in git-bash in Windows]

Comment: While executing this command in the windows slave machine, I'm getting the following error "'xargs' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

Comment: This assumes you run it in git-bash environment (different from regular command line), which has access to the additional unix tools