# copy folders from different sources to a new destination in cmd

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, cmd

I have a `txt` file that contains full paths of folders.
I want to copy these folders to a new directory. For example, lets say that my `txt` file contains :

```
C:\tools\folderA
C:\tools\folderB
C:\temp\abc\folderC
```

I want to copy `folderA`, `folderB`, `folderC` to a new destination.
How can I do so?

Comment: There are [lots of similar questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=batch+copy+folders+list)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Batch: Copy a list (txt) of files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6257948/batch-copy-a-list-txt-of-files)

Answer (score 0):

```
for /F "delims=," %%V in (.\myFolders.txt) do (
  xcopy /E /I "%%~V" "%outDir%\allFolders\%%~nV"
)
```

Comment: Good answers *explain* as well as provide code. Consider updating your answer to include an explanation about how this code works and why it is the best option.