# How to batch copy files based on a list (txt) of PREFIXES

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, copy, xcopy

My filenames contain somewhat standardized prefixes. Generally, the format is `yyyy-99999-xx`.

Filename examples:

```
2015-12345-NY-0 Coney Island
2015-12345-NY-1 Coney Island
2015-54321-NY Coney Island
```

As you can see, there can be multiple files containing identical characters `1` thru `n`. I would like to copy files from a folder by searching for prefixes contained in a .txt file list.

Basically, I would like to "refine/expand" the process shown in [Batch: Copy a list (txt) of files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6257948/batch-copy-a-list-txt-of-files)  so that `file-list.txt` - I've changed to `Prefix-List.txt` - contains only the filename "prefixes" of the files to copy.  I had to change the **xcopy** switch to `/K` in order to copy any files.

Additionally, I would like to redirect errors to `Errors.txt`

"Nice to have" would be including subfolders in the search.

Using my filename examples above:

`2015` would copy 3 files.
`2015-12345-NY` would copy 2 files.
`2015-12345-NY-1` would copy 1 file.

Here's my .bat file

```
set src_folder=d:\JAR\source
set dst_folder=d:\JAR\destination
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (File-list.txt) DO (
    xcopy /K "%src_folder%\%%i" "%dst_folder%"
)
```

---

Mofi's solution is exactly what I asked for.  Now I'd like to expand a little by changing the destination directory name & adding a date-time prefix.

I have 2 questions
     1. How to get Mon=08 (instead of Aug)?
     2. What is syntax for MKDIR using a variable?

Here's the coding I'm using (modified from [Windows batch: formatted date into variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10945572/windows-batch-formatted-date-into-variable) ).

```
 @echo off
 setlocal 
 for /f "skip=8 tokens=2,3,4,5,6,7,8 delims=: " %%D in ('robocopy /l * \ \  /ns /nc /ndl /nfl /np /njh /XF * /XD *') do (
 set "dow=%%D"
 set "month=%%E"
 set "day=%%F"
 set "HH=%%G"
 set "MM=%%H"
 set "SS=%%I"
 set "year=%%J"
 SET "DESTINATION=%%J%%E%%F%%G%%H%%I-EXTRACTION"
)

 echo Day of the week: %dow%
 echo Day of the month : %day%
 echo Month : %month%
 echo hour : %HH%
 echo minutes : %MM%
 echo seconds : %SS%
 echo year : %year%
 echo DESTINATION : %DESTINATION%

 endlocal

 MKDIR {"%DESTINATION%"}
```

Comment: With only a cursory look, if these are prefixes, then a wildcard needs to be specified. `xcopy /K "%src_folder%\%%i*" "%dst_folder%")`

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't have a lot of testing, but it might point in the right direction.

```
set src_folder=d:\JAR\source
set dst_folder=d:\JAR\destination
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (File-list.txt) DO (
    for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%k in (`dir /s /b "%src_folder%\%%i*") DO
        xcopy /K "%%k" "%dst_folder%"
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion for this little batch file with comments:

```
@echo off
rem Define source and destination directory.
set "src_folder=d:\JAR\source"
set "dst_folder=d:\JAR\destination"

rem Delete error log file from a previous run.
del Errors.txt 2>nul

rem Copy all files in all subdirectories matching
rem any prefix string in prefix list text file.
for /F "delims=" %%i in (Prefix-List.txt) do (
    xcopy "%src_folder%\%%i*" "%dst_folder%" /C /H /I /K /Q /R /S /Y >nul 2>>Errors.txt
)

rem Delete Errors.txt if it is empty because of no error.
for %%F in (Errors.txt) do if %%~zF == 0 del Errors.txt
```

But I doubt you are really happy with error information as **xcopy** error messages are really not useful without printing copied files to console and redirecting them all into the text file, too.

For details on the used command, open a command prompt window, run there the following commands and read all output help pages.

- `del /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `set /?`
- `xcopy /?`

---

Extensions:

1. Make the source folder a variable passed via first parameter to batch file on execution.
   Display an error message if batch file is executed without a parameter.
   Display an error message if specified source folder does not exist.
2. Prefix `yyyy-mm-dd_` for destination directory independent on local date format.

This modified version of above batch file includes the two extensions:

```
@echo off
rem Check first parameter of batch file.
if "%~1" == "" goto NoSourceFolder
if not exist "%~1" goto SourceNotExist
if not exist Prefix-List.txt goto NoPrefixList

setlocal
rem Define source directory based on parameter.
set "src_folder=%~1"

rem Get local date and time in a language independent format.
for /F "tokens=2 delims==." %%T in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe OS GET LocalDateTime /VALUE') do set "LocalDate=%%T"

rem Define local date in format yyyy-mm-dd.
set "LocalDate=%LocalDate:~0,4%-%LocalDate:~4,2%-%LocalDate:~6,2%"

rem Define destination directory with date prefix.
set "dst_folder=d:\JAR\%LocalDate%_destination"

rem Delete error log file from a previous run.
del Errors.txt 2>nul

rem Copy all files in all subdirectories matching
rem any prefix string in prefix list text file.
for /F "delims=" %%i in (Prefix-List.txt) do (
    xcopy "%src_folder%\%%i*" "%dst_folder%" /C /H /I /K /Q /R /S /Y >nul 2>>Errors.txt
)

rem Delete Errors.txt if it is empty because of no error.
for %%F in (Errors.txt) do if %%~zF == 0 del Errors.txt
endlocal
goto :EOF

:NoSourceFolder
echo %~nx0: Missing source folder name as first parameter.
goto HaltOnError

:SourceNotExist
echo %~nx0: There is no folder "%~1".
goto HaltOnError

:NoPrefixList
echo %~nx0: There is no file "%CD%\Prefix-List.txt".

:HaltOnError
echo.
pause
```

Thanks goes to [Jay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20840/jay) for answer on [How to get current datetime on Windows command line, in a suitable format for using in a filename?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/203116/3074564)

For details on `%~1` and `%~nx0` run in a command prompt window `call /?` and read all the output help pages, and read also [What does %~dp0 mean, and how does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034076/).

Comment: How can I modify to    
1. Make the Source directory a variable; to be supplied at run time?    
2. Add a yyyy-mm-dd prefix to the Destination folder name?