# batch file to copy a list of files from a text file

Tags: list, batch-file, copy

I'm trying to make a batch file to copy files from a text list to a folder. The code was copied in this forum but it doesn't work.

The text list is in the desktop.

list.txt

and contains, for example,

C:\Users...\Desktop\Test\item1.ipt
C:\Users...\Desktop\Test\item2.ipt
C:\Users...\Desktop\Test\item3.ipt
C:\Users...\Desktop\Test\item4.ipt
C:\Users...\Desktop\Test\item5.ipt
C:\Users...\Desktop\Test\item6.ipt

and my batch file is also in the desktop.

```
@echo off 
FOR /F "delims=" %%a IN (C:\Users\...\Desktop\list.txt) DO COPY "%%~a" "C:\Users\...\Desktop\Temp\%%~nxa"
```

Both files (batch and txt) are in the desktop, so can I delete the path of the text file?

```
@echo off 
FOR /F "delims=" %%a IN (list.txt) DO COPY "%%~a" "C:\Users\...\Desktop\Temp\%%~nxa"
```

Thanks for your help.

EDIT: The ideia is to get the file location in the text file, so directories in the text file are variables.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Batch: Copy a list (txt) of files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6257948/batch-copy-a-list-txt-of-files)

Comment: I saw that, Trimax, but it's not the same. I don't want to set a source dir. I want to copy all the line (path with the file) to a new folder, so the source dir is variable...

Comment: To search a file in the directory holding the batch file, use `%~dp0list.txt`; just using `list.txt` meaning `.\list.txt` points to the current working directory, which is not necessarily the same...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off
pushd "%userprofile%\Desktop"
FOR /F "delims=" %%a IN (list.txt) DO COPY "%%~a" ".\Temp\%%~nxa"
popd
```

In the above code snippet:

- [`pushd` command](https://ss64.com/nt/pushd.html): *Change the current directory/folder and store the previous folder/path for use by the `POPD` command*.
- `%userprofile%` is a [standard (built-in) Environment Variable](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html)
- a period in `".\Temp\%%~nxa"` is a [directory component in a path representing the current directory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx). Hence, `".\Temp\%%~nxa"` has the same effect as `"Temp\%%~nxa"`.
- `POPD` command: [*Change directory back to the path/folder most recently stored by the `PUSHD` command*](https://ss64.com/nt/popd.html).

**Edit**. Above ´for /F´ loop does do nothing silently if the `list.txt` is empty, or if it contains only empty lines and standard delimiters, or if it start with some control characters, e.g. `NULL` character, or if it is saved using `UTF-16` encoding.:

```
==> type null_and_data.txt
 1st line
2nd
3rd

==> FOR /F "delims=" %a IN (null_and_data.txt) DO @echo "%~a"

==> powershell -c "(type null_and_data.txt -Encoding byte -TotalCount 16) -Join ','"
0,49,115,116,32,108,105,110,101,32,13,10,50,110,100,13

==>
```

Some of above scenarios (in particular, the latter one) *could* be solved by using [`type` command](https://ss64.com/nt/type.html) as follows:

```
@echo off
pushd "%userprofile%\Desktop"
FOR /F "delims=" %%a IN ('type list.txt') DO COPY "%%~a" ".\Temp\%%~nxa"
popd
```

Example:

```
==> FOR /F "delims=" %a IN (fileUTF16LEBOM.txt) DO @echo "%~a"

==> type fileUTF16LEBOM.txt
x
y

==> FOR /F "delims=" %a IN ('type fileUTF16LEBOM.txt') DO @echo "%~a"
"x"
"y"

==>
```

Comment: Thanks, JosefZ, but it doesn't work. No error messages, but nothing.