# Git: Get a list of files/folder committed and pushed in crrent branch

Tags: git, version-control

Is there any tool or a way to download/list only those files/folders which were changed and committed/pushed in a specific branch and it should not include those files which are unchanged since the branch was created till now.

The purpose is to make a zip archive as a build which will contains only the changed/modified files/folders only, so that other files should remain intact.

Thanks.

Comment: This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4541300/6309

Comment: @VonC I don't want to give commit ids, I want everything changed since the birth of this branch.

Comment: Git does not record "birth of branch"; you will have to do that separately.  For instance, when you create the branch, you could create a tag as well: branch-foo goes with tag-mark-foo.  Later, when you're ready to generate a diff, `git diff tag-mark-foo branch-foo` will get you the changes since the tag (which, since you tagged the point you want to diff from, is ... where you want to diff from).

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comment above by *@VonC* you can use `git diff-tree`

Another way to do it is to use the git log in a various ways:

```
git log ^commit1 commit2
git log commit1 ^commit2
git log commit1...commit
```

Depends what you want to display.

For example:

## ***`Find out the base commit for the diff`***

***[`git-merge-base`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-base)***

> git merge-base finds best common ancestor(s) between two commits to use in a three-way merge.

Use this command to find out the commit to start with and then use the sample code below to print out the statistics.

---

```
# display the statistics of a given range,
# When given a range of commits to display
git log --stat --oneline HEAD...HEAD~5
```

[image]