# git repository - copy changed files to new directory

Tags: git, diff

1. I have `git-repository` for web-project with several files in several directories.
2. I make changes in some files, `commit` them.
3. Now I need `diff` current updated state and state before update and **copy all files (with proper directories) that were changed into separate directory (out of git) to load them on server.**

How can I do the 3-d part?

Comment: Possibly same as: [Export Only Modified/Added Files With Folder Structure in Git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4541300/export-only-modified-and-added-files-with-folder-structure-in-git) ? This should help

Comment: Thank you, Dan D! It was I was looking for

Comment: NP glad I could help @DaneSoul