# How to download the diffs present in the staging area in git

Tags: git

Is there a way to download the diffs of the files present in staging area in git other than git stash. I would probably want a way to download the diffs as a tar ball?

Answer (score 1):

Since [`git archive`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive) works only with a treeish, you would need to:

- make a commit out of your current index
- export those files as an archive, as mentioned in "[Export only modified and added files with folder structure in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20686113/6309)"
- [`git reset`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset) (to restore the index)

That is:

```
git add .
git commit -m "tmp commit for export"
git archive -o patch.zip @ $(git diff --name-only @~..@)
git reset @~
```

Note: if you have spaces in the pathnames of those files, you might need instead:

```
git diff -z --name-only @~ @ | xargs -0 git archive -o patch.zip @
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that:

- Your work is already placed in staging area with `git add <filename>`
- You don't want to create temporary commits just for the sake of saving the work
- You want one diff/patch per versioned file

```
for f in $(git diff --cached --name-only); do \
   p="$f.patch"; git diff --cached -- "$f" > "$p" && zip p.zip "$p" && rm "$p"; \
done
  adding: file-1.c.patch (deflated 36%)
  adding: file-2.c.patch (deflated 44%)
```

Viewing the archive contents:

```
unzip -l p.zip 
Archive:  p.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
      259  2016-08-07 19:24   file-1.c.patch
      347  2016-08-07 19:24   file-2.c.patch
---------                     -------
      606                     2 files
```