# Create git archive from repo without a commit

Tags: git, zip, tar, git-archive

There is the `git archive` command - is there a way to create a tarball from a repo without making a commit? Essentially I just want to create tarball of the existing files (more importantly honoring gitignore).  I assume git archive is looking for a commit - but I just want a snapshot of the code even for uncommitted changes.

Another way to do this would just be to write a program that will tar all the files and ignore what's in gitignore, but that would require writing that program.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to download the diffs present in the staging area in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38816424/how-to-download-the-diffs-present-in-the-staging-area-in-git)

Comment: @Joe: that suggested duplicate is about making an archive that contains *only* the files that are *different* from the `HEAD` files.  This question asks for an archive of what *would* be committed, if you committed.

Answer (score 2):

`git archive` requires a treeish to use, which means you need a tree, commit, or tag. There's nothing preventing you from creating a temporary branch and a commit with the contents you want and archiving that.

Alternatively, if you're certain you don't care about the ignored files, you can run `git clean -dffx` and then use `tar --exclude-vcs` to package your archive. You could also skip the `git clean` invocation and try `tar --exclude-vcs --exclude-vcs-ignores`.

Answer (score 1):

The simple and easy and obviously correct way to do it is: just make a commit (as [bk2204 suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55977933/1256452)).

But, since `git archive` takes a `<tree-ish>`, you *can* do this without making a commit.  Just make the tree *part* of a commit, which is half (or more) of an actual commit, and then use that:

```
git archive [additional options] $(git write-tree)
```

The issue here is that `git write-tree` will write whatever is in the *index* right now.  This means you need to add all updated files to the index, even if you're not going to make a commit.  You could do that with a temporary index, if you want to get extra fancy, but it's easier to just `add -u` first:

```
git add -u
git archive [additional options] $(git write-tree)
```

Another way to get the work-tree files into a commit, without making a commit yourself, is to use `git stash` to do the job.  This will write the current work-tree to a new commit.  Hence:

```
git stash push
git archive [additional options] refs/stash
git stash pop --index
```

would do the job, more or less.  The *less* occurs when there is nothing to stash, in which case `git stash push` does nothing and you should not run `git stash pop`.  In this particular case, you can archive `HEAD`—but it's annoying to detect whether `git stash push` did anything.  You can add more layers of scripting to deal with that, but really, what's wrong with just committing now?

Comment: I would just use a temporary branch but when I do that I end up working off that branch by accident because my script to return to previous branch fails or whatever. I was thinking about doing some sort of "virtual branch" which would not effect the state of the original repo at all somehow. To do this virtual branch I could take a shallow clone of the repo to some temp location on disk?

Comment: Also, `tar` takes a `T` command, you can do `git ls-files | tar Tcf - my.tar` to make the archive from the current worktree content  without the write-tree, and `git ls-files --exclude-standard -oc | tar Tcf - my.tar` to tar up every file that `git add .` would see.

Comment: @jthill: depends on your version of tar, though it seems to be present in FreeBSD and Linux today at least. I don't recall it in Solaris or 4.4BSD tar... The 1997 POSIX standard doesn't have it: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xcu/tar.html - but pax reads files from stdin, and can write tar format: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xcu/pax.html

Comment: I don't know whether the mingw environment includes `pax`; POSIX is very weird about pax/cpio/tar ... it doesn't include `tar` or `cpio` at all.  But yeah, I think  `git ls-files | pax -w my.tar` would do it too if the command's there.

Answer (score 1):

In addition of making a commit, consider [**`git bundle`**](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle): it is like `git archive`... but with history.

You get one file (a bundle file), that you can copy around, and then *clone* back from.
See "[Fully backup a git repo?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5578292/6309)" for more.