# Package modified/new files with folder structure for a given feature in Git

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, git-diff

I would like to get all changed (i.e. modified and newly added) files with folder structure committed into a feature branch, so that I can export them and generate a zip "package".

Similar to [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4541300/export-only-modified-and-added-files-with-folder-structure-in-git), the idea is to get the package and extract it on the server but NOT for a specific commit, but for all commits against a feature branch created via Sourcetree. Is this possible? I have Googled it but most results describe how to do it against a commit.

My apologies if my post is not clear enough. I've added an image to illustrate what I'm trying to achieve.

I've highlighted 8 commits in blue, and there are more further down the list, all against the same feature "#161690_affectedAppl..." over a period of time. I want to get all the changes made in these commits. The feature "#161690_affectedAppl..." is obviously "aware" of what changes it contains so I want to get all the changed files in a zip that belong to this feature
[image: Souretree feature]

I've done this in the past via Sourcetree terminal against a feature, but it's not always accurate.

```
git archive -o c:\release_featureName.zip HEAD $(git diff --name-only HEAD@{"21 days ago"} --diff-filter=ACMRTUXB)
```

Comment: The `git archive` command makes a zip (or tar) archive from a single commit. The archive format is really only *suited* to making an archive from a single commit, as both a commit *and* an archive are representations of a snapshot of source code. (The commit is an augmented snapshot, saving both the code *and* some metadata; tar and zip archives don't have the same kind of metadata, but one could certainly wedge some in.)

Comment: @torek thank you for the explanation re. git archive, however I'm still looking for an answer on how to obtain all changes made in a feature branch created via Sourcetree which can contain multiple commits.

Comment: Well, the usual way to get all the *commits* would be to run `git fetch`. Of course that requires having a Git repository, but that's clearly the right way to do it. If what you want is a set of email-able patches (rather than commits), you can use `git format-patch` to get that.

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, you could use the same `git diff-tree` approach, and pass two commits instead of one (i.e. get the files that changed between the two commits, and zip/tar/whatever).

Comment: @Hasturkun I've updated the initial post just to make it clear. I've had a look at git diff-tree again, that seems to work against a commit id but will not give me all the changes as highlighted the image I posted